Cannot generate ecore tool model from genmodel because of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
I'm currently trying to generate my ecore model with ecoretools 0.10 and Java 11, i'm on eclipse 4.24.
When I click Generate All or Generate Model Code on my genmodel i got the following error who is absolutely not clear
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1841)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenBaseImpl.appendAnnotationInfo(GenBaseImpl.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenFeatureImpl.getModelInfo(GenFeatureImpl.java:2431)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenFeatureImpl.getModelInfo(GenFeatureImpl.java:2230)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.templates.model.Class$2.run(Class.java:1882)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.templates.model.Class.generate(Class.java:3920)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generateJava(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:1979)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateInterface(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenClassGeneratorAdapter.generateModel(GenClassGeneratorAdapter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.generator.GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.doGenerate(GenBaseGeneratorAdapter.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.AbstractGeneratorAdapter.generate(AbstractGeneratorAdapter.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.presentation.GeneratorUIUtil$GeneratorOperation.execute(GeneratorUIUtil.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.lambda$0(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122) 

I've tried to compile my model which is good but do not regenerate my code.
I also tried to recreate my genmodel but still have the problem.
I also remove all appendAnotationInfo with no success.
What I am missing ?

Are you sure about that ecoretools version number? It was over a decade ago, and if correct, the very first thing to do is update to the current release. https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.ecoretools
